# Confusing diagram for LRU cache replacement strategy

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, lru

[image]

The LRU algorithm is explained with the Picture above about the cache in computer architecture.  It's copyrighted by J. Brehm (editor's note: presumably from a book or online material?)

I have searched for and understood the explanations online to the algorithm but no model matched the image.

Could you explain the picture to me?

Answer (score 2):

- LRU blocknum(b)er is initialized to 0.
- Block-Frame Address (Adresse) is the cache block access pattern.
- Until block 0 is accessed, LRU is set to 0. Subsequently, the LRU blocknumber corresponds to the least recently used block.